# VideoLan.Net: Play media backwards / Change playback speed?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, audio, video, libvlc

I have been given a new requirement that I make the option available to play media files in reverse, and the option to be able to increase/decrease playback speed.

The program with which I am working relies on VideoLan.Net to handle all our media playback needs, so the question I have is this:

Using VideoLan.Net, is it possible to play media backwards, and is it possible to increase/decrease the playback speed?

Comment: vlc can not play media in reverse. I don't know about VideoLan.Net, but with LibVLC it certainly is possible to increase/decrease the playback speed, see libvlc_media_player_set_rate().

Comment: Excellent thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed to know. If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vlc can not play media in reverse.

With LibVLC it certainly is possible to increase/decrease the playback speed: see `libvlc_media_player_set_rate(float rate)`.

Use e.g `0.5f` for half speed, `1.0f` to return to normal speed, `2.0f` for double speed and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **position**, remembering that it implies a little *play* (used by VLC in order to re-render):

```
float deltaStep = (float)60000 / vlcControl.Length;
float backwardStep = deltaStep * 0.0000015f;

while (vlcControl.Position > backwardStep)
{
    vlcControl.Position -= backwardStep * vlcControl.Rate;
}
```

For increasing/decreasing/normalizing playback speed:

```
vlcControl.Rate *= 2; // Faster
...
vlcControl.Rate /= 2; // Slower
...
vlcControl.Rate = 1.0f; // Normal
```