# set playback speed in vlc dot net (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, video, media-player, libvlc

i am using [vlc player](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) in winforms. its working fine, but the problem is that its playing faster.
 i have videos recorded at 10fps. i think vlcControl is playing at 30fps, that's why video are playing faster. Referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949702/videolan-net-play-media-backwards-change-playback-speed), but it didn't help. i couldn't find any function like `set_play_back_speed` function under vlcControl1.Video
I thought vlcControl would automatically figure out fps & play accordingly.
 if i open the same video from vlc media player installed on my windows pc, it plays at proper rate.
any clue how to fix this?

P.S: if i open any video recorded at 29.97fps, vlcControl in winforms is playing it at proper speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there's no function to set FPS to video thru Vlc.DotNet and I am not sure are you using WinForms or WPF application, but best I can help is probably, if you would play with rate settings as in transpone video.

It's found at vlcControl1.rate (which is float value default is 1.00), if you have 30fps and only want 10fps well, you could try to set:

```
vlcControl1.rate = (int)(33 / 100);
```

Which then would decrease video and audio transpone to 10fps from 30fps (assuming 1.00 = 30fps).

Comment: !Not sure about this!, but there's also video/audio sync enabled at VideoLAN by default. You might be able to disable all sync at VlcMediaPlayerOptions at start time OR by opening regular VLC and disable sync and then load the libvlc from same path where VideoLAN player is (some of the functions can be disabled directly with VideoLAN even before opening player at C# code).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. like i mentioned in question, i'm using in winforms. i tried setting rate to 0.33 before playing video in code, it was pretty slow, so my assumption that vlc was playing at 33fps was wrong. it was playing at 10fps itself i guess, because when i set Rate to 0.9, it was  playing fine (its not playing faster than the live recording). any other value would make vlc to play faster or slower. at the moment i'm only focusing at video, so audio sync can be checked later.

but how to determine with what fps vlc is playing video?

Thanks

Comment: Well, only thing I can think of is the vsync(Vertical sync) by video card drivers as 30 fps sounds like half of 60hz monitor locking the speed to 30,60,120 fps depending of monitor refresh rate. So, try without the "vlcControl1.rate" setting and try to disable/turn off the vsync at 3D settings of video card drivers.

Comment: hmm, took some to find, but here is an option to force FPS it seems: ":screen-fps=30.000000" you can set that as VlcMediaPlayerOptions. ex. ":screen-fps=10.000000" I am not sure how well that works as of my testing fails still to be accurate. (Works with VLC 2.#).

Comment: i couldn't find screen-fps under VlcMediaPlayerOptions... ru sure that 'screen-fps' is available in [this](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) library?

Comment: It might be that this option is only available while capturing device, but since it's same as playback of media was thinking it should work. I haven't been able to test it will test it today. However, I think if you force vsync down from GPU or by player that alone should work as that is only thing that would force 10fps media to play at 30fps which btw you should check with something like fraps, Rivatuner or MSI Afterburner to identify what the playback actual FPS is. (Sorry for long answer time have been busy)